# Trivial normal bundle $NS$ equivalence

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I am trying to prove the following assertion:

> Suppose S is a properly embbeded submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ of
>   codimension $k$. Show that the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists a neighborhood $U$ of $S$ in $\mathbb R ^n$ and a smooth function $\Phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ such that $S$ is a regular
>      level set of $\Phi$.
> 2. The normal bundle $NS$ is a trivial vector bundle

This is an exercise of the book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds - John M. Lee* and I don't have a clue how to start to prove this.

Comment: I'm a little confused. A regular level set of single smooth function can only be codimension 1. Why does it mention the codimension as $k$?

Comment: @ziggurism: The question (Problem 10-18 on page 271 of my book) is misquoted above -- it should say "a smooth function $\Phi\colon U\to \mathbb R^k$," not $U\to S$. And it does indeed apply to codimension $k$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ all the way, so the computations are more concrete.

To see why $(1) \implies (2)$, we can use the fact that we have a very explicit derivative for $\Phi$:

$$\Phi'_p=\begin{pmatrix} \nabla \Phi_1 \\
\nabla\Phi_2 \\
\cdots \\
\nabla \Phi_k
\end{pmatrix}. $$

Since we are supposing $S$ is a regular level set, we have that those $\nabla \Phi_i$ are all linearly independent along $S$. They are also all normal to $S$, since $\Phi$ is constant there. This gives a global framing of the normal bundle.

To see why $(2) \implies (1)$, you simply use the fact that by assumption there exists a diffeomorphism $\Psi: NS \to S \times \mathbb{R}^k$, and consider $\Phi:=\pi_2 \circ \Psi \circ T,$ where $T: U \to V \subset NS $ is a diffeomorphism of a neighbourhood of $S$ onto a neighbourhood of the zero section on the normal bundle (such diffeomorphism is given by the tubular neighbourhood theorem).

Answer (score 0):

$1\Rightarrow 2:$ Since $S$ is a level set of only a single function, that means it has codimension $1.$ Since it is a level set of the function $\Phi,$ that means $d\Phi$ is a differential form which vanishes on all tangent vectors to $S$, and does not vanish for any vectors not tangent to $S$. Using an inner product, we may turn $d\Phi$ into a vector field, nowhere vanishing, and normal, along $S$. Hence the rank one normal bundle is trivial.

$2\Rightarrow 1:$ Take a global section $v$ of $NS$. Define $\Phi(p,t) = \exp(tv_p)$.

Answer (score 0):

The "gradient" solution for $(1) \implies (2$) works, but Lee doesn't actually define the gradient until the next chapter.  However, there's a simpler solution using materials at hand.  Write $\pi:NS \to S$ for the bundle projection map, and $\pi_2:T\mathbb{R}^k = \mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k$ for the canonical projection, then $\langle \pi,\pi_2\circ d\Phi\rangle:NS \to S\times \mathbb{R}^k$ is a global trivialization of $NS$.

(This is really the same as the gradient solution BTW.)